# How can I convert bytearray to String

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am extracting metadata of a song using following code ,And how I can convert the byte array (buf) to string? Please help me,Thanks in advance.

```
String mint = httpConnection.getHeaderField("icy-metaint");
int b = 0;
int count =0;    
while(count++ < length){
b = inputStream.read();         
}            
int metalength = ((int)b)*16;
if(metalength <= 0)
    return;
byte buf[] = new byte[metalength];
inputStream.read(buf,0,buf.length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). Read bytes from the stream:

```
// use net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities
byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream);
```

2). Create a String from the bytes:

```
String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

This implies you know the encoding the text data was encoded with before sending from the server. In the example right above the encoding is UTF-8. BlackBerry supports the following character encodings:

```
* "ISO-8859-1"
* "UTF-8"
* "UTF-16BE"
* "US-ASCII"
```

The default encoding is "ISO-8859-1". So when you use `String(byte[] data)` constructor it is the same as `String(byte[] data, "ISO-8859-1")`.

If you don't know what encoding the server uses then I'd recommend to try UTF-8 first, because by now it has almost become a default one for servers. Also note the server may send the encoding via an http header, so you can extract it from the response. However I saw a lot of servers which put "UTF-8" into the header while actually use ISO-8859-1 or even ASCII for the data encoding.

Answer (score 2):

`String` has a constructor that accepts a byte array that you can use for this.
See e.g. http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Are you sure that the data that you are trying to convert to a String is actually human-readable data?

Answer (score 1):

As @Heiko mentioned you can create string directly using the constructor. This applies to blackberry java too:

```
byte[] array = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
String str = new String(array);
```

Comment: I tried    String s = new String(buf,"ISO-8859-1");But still only some part of s be in string format